# Copying from multiple location or appending from file to file

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, yeoman

In nodejs , I want to copy multiple files to a single file and want to append one file into another file, What is the function name?

```js
this.fs.copy(
            this.templatePath('testing.json' + 'testing2.json'),
            this.destinationPath('public/index.html')
          )
```

like this, I want to copy from multiple location to single file

```js
this.fs.appendFile('public/index.html', 'hdjkfhsdjkfh');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no single function to fit your specific need in the built-in modules.

I suggest you use `readFileSync` in a loop first, concatenate them and use `writeFileSync` to write to your destination.

The append task could be done similarly with `readDileSync` then use `appendFileSync`

If you want to use async operations, I suggest you try the fs.promise namespace which simplifies the async with loop scenario.

If what you are doing is merging assets for a frontend page, I suggest you look into tools like webpack to automate this process.